# Modify all attributes of a Laravel model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

Accessors will do their job on a single attribute perfectly, but I need a way to have a method to do an Accessor/Getter job on all attributes and automatically.

The purpose is that I want to replace some characters/numbers on getting attributes and then printing them out. I can do it from within controller and manually but I think it would be great to have it from model side and automatically.

Like overriding `getAttributes()` method:

```
public function getAttributes()
{
    foreach ($this->attributes as $key => $value) {
        $this->attributes[$key] = str_replace([...], [...], $value);
    }
    return $this->attributes;
}
```

But I have to call it every time on model `$model->getAttributes();`

Any way to do it automatically and DRY?

Comment: How about overriding the constructor and use parent::__construct()? Or add new class extend model use construct and let models extend that new class so it's applied to all.

Comment: @TimvanUum Actually I did that but I think there should be something wrong as it didn't affect results at all!

Comment: Strange just tried it myself and indeed it doesn't work. Even when calling the fill method again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like:

```
public function getAttribute($key)
{
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->attributes) || $this->hasGetMutator($key)) {
        if($key === 'name') return 'modify this value';
        return $this->getAttributeValue($key);
    }

    return $this->getRelationValue($key);
}
```

It's fully overriding the default method so be a bit careful.

**EDIT**

Also check out: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators

Comment: Excellent solution to override `getAttribute`. However mutators are called when setting a value, which is not the purpose here.

Comment: could you explain your comment a bit further. Or maybe clarify why this solution does not work?

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Could you please explain why the solution does not work? Do you get an error? Do you not get the results you want? This function can be added to the specific model class (like User) or create a new class (CustomBaseModel) that extends model and add it there and let model extends that new class. Change if($key === 'name') to what you want to change or remove to change all. Use: $this->getAttributeValue($key); to modify the value

Comment: Oh sorry, i should have been clearer. I answered specifically to that sentence.:  "However mutators are called when setting a value, which is not the purpose here." There is nothing wrong with your solution, although I would go the way with overriding the magic __get() Method.

Comment: I ended up using your solution within a custom model and extending it except on users model.

Comment: can you share a working example?  i do know. how to use this? i just paste in the model. but how to call?

Answer (score 2):

I would go with following approach and override the models __get method:

```
public function __get($key)
{
    $excluded = [
        // here you should add primary or foreign keys and other values,
        // that should not be touched.
        // $alternatively define an $included array to whitelist values
        'foreignkey', 
    ];

    // if mutator is defined for an attribute it has precedence.
    if(array_key_exists($key, $this->attributes)
       && ! $this->hasGetMutator($key) && ! in_array($key, $excluded))  {
        return "modified string";
    }

    // let everything else handle the Model class itself
    return parent::__get($key);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How about running it with each Creating and Updating events. So you can do something like that:

```
public function boot()
    {
        Model::creating(function ($model)
            return $model->getAttributes();   //or $this->getAttributes()
        });
        Model::updating(function ($model)
            return $model->getAttributes();   //or $this->getAttributes()
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does `model::creating()` fire on instantiating of model?

Comment: Just before saving it, you can use saving() to replace both updating and creating

Comment: You mistaken. I'm not going to do it on saving but on getting. I talked about accessors not mutators.